# Load an iframe asynchronously

Tags: iframe, asynchronous

I have a webpage with an `<iframe>` pointing to another website. I don't want this to block the loading of the rest of the page. Is there a way to load it asyncrounously?

Comment: Which loading do you want to block? What do you mean by asynchronously?

Comment: Are you having problems with a page load being blocked?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It shouldn't block. If you want the main page to fully load first (eg, main page's images before iframe content) then you'll have to use a bit of javascript to set the url of the iframe, like `<body onload="javascript:...">`

Comment: Main document's `onload` won't fire until all iframes have been loaded.

Comment: you can dynamically create iframe via javascript on page load and append it in document

Answer (score 14):

Using jQuery, this works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function() {
    var f = document.createElement('iframe');
    f.src = url; 
    f.width = 1000; 
    f.height = 500;
    $('body').append(f);
  });
</script>
```

where `url` is some URL.

Comment: edited as window.load is deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

One problem we had was that while iframes already do load asynchronously, the main page will not fire OnLoad until the iframe has finished loading too.

We worked around this by 'faking' OnLoad by calling the method we wanted in a script element at the bottom of the main page, even outside the closing body tag:

```
</body>
<script  type='text/jscript' language='javascript'>
BodyOnready();
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think @Coxy is correct that the OnLoad won't fire. At least when running some web page performance tests it seemed to me it is waiting for the iframe to consider the page to be fully loaded. I therefore use this small jQuery snippet to load the iframe:

HTML:
`<iframe id="blabla"></iframe>`

JS:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   if ($('#blabla').length <= 0) { return; }  // to avoid errors in case the element doesn't exist on the page / removed.
   $('#blabla').attr('src','//example.com/page');
});
```

Comment: Using any version of jQuery there is no need to check `$('#blabla').length`. If the selector is empty, the `.attr` will just do anything.

Comment: I have the same issue - web performance tests are waiting for the iframes. This solution didn't work for me though, I tried all combinations of updating the `src` or creating the `iframe` after load - as far as I can see (from the Chrome loading animation) it still waits for the `iframe` to be loaded :( Of course, if I manually update the `iframe` `src` in the console it works fine! I have no idea where I should bind the update function to avoid prolonged loading state.

Answer (score 4):

you can wait until after 'onload' has fired to set the iframe's src:

```
<body onload="loadFrame">
```

then something like this:

```
function loadFrame(){
    var myFrame = document.getElementById('myFrame');
    myFrame.src = "myURL";
};
```

Comment: Brilliant, increased google page insights score by 20!

Answer (score 4):

Some vanilla JS alternative:

HTML:

```
<iframe id="YOURID" src="about:blank">Loading...</iframe>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('YOURID').src = 'https://insertYourUrlHere.com'
};
```

Comment: There is no `text/jscript` mime type, why did you think there was? If you think there is, then first google it and make sure.

Answer (score 3):

iframes should load asynchronously without any effort on your part.

Comment: Iframes loads asynchronously but blocks window.onload event. Here's some explanation and workaround http://www.lognormal.com/blog/2012/12/12/the-script-loader-pattern/

Answer (score 2):

Although I agree this shouldn't be happening, you could wait for your webpage to be completely loaded, and then load the iframe contents. With jQuery, I think you can do something like this:

- Supposing your IFRAME looks like: `<iframe name="theOtherPage"></iframe>`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  (window.frames || document.frames)["theOtherPage"].window.location = "http://theotherpage.com/"; 
});
```

Comment: This did not work for me.  I was testing in Firefox, but I doubt that matters.

Comment: @CaptainBli, I've updated the code. I think now it should work.

Comment: Nope. `$(document).ready` runs on DOMContentLoaded, before onload. Setting the src before onload means it will still block onload. Demo: https://codepen.io/mac9416/pen/qQLeyP