# How to start loading an iframe before the DOM is loaded

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom, iframe

I have a question that is the oppsite of this: [load an iframe asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114239/is-there-a-way-to-load-an-iframe-asynchronously). I need to start loading the `iframe` the moment the browser starts loading the page, and not after the DOM has finished loading.

How can I force the load of the `iframe` before the DOM is loaded? Before the `document.ready` event?

I tried using an `UpdatePanel` around the iframe that starts an async postback, but I get a lot of javascript exception that crash the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your HTML just contain the IFRAME, and an onload event for the IFRAME that injects the rest of your HTML into your DOM.

Comment: Good idea, but I have a master page. Is your solution possible with a master page?

Comment: Sure, but I wouldn't want to do this for every page in the site. What is the IFRAME for?

Comment: The `iframe` is only on one page. The `iframe` is for hotel booking information from another site that handles availability and booking.