# Dynamic Asynch Iframe technique

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamic, asynchronous

**Situation:** I need to create an iframe within a page in a dynamic asynchronous way as described in [Iframe loading techniques and performance](http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/iframe-loading-techniques-performance) blog post by aaron peters, I read the blog post many times and even watched the original presentation given at velocity conf where this technique was first introduced by Meebo's engineers (as mentioned in the blog post)..

I'm not a JS expert, but the code seems straight forward to me. I don't think his demo page works properly either (Iframe appears blank)! and the technique isn't that popular online, I hope the answer to this question will act as a reference where people can just copy paste the code with minimal modifications to create iframes with all the goodness the technique has to offer.

Briefly explained:

- The technique prevents the Iframe from blocking
  the page on-load while waiting for the Iframe *and* the rest of the DOM to fully load first.
- It prevents the browser's busy indicator from working for
  however long it takes everything to load, thus better user experience.
- Using this technique, the Iframe starts loading its content **before** the on-load of the main page fires (Iframe starts to load early = shows up early = better speed performance), so please don't suggest answers of ways to modify an iframe's src or append an iframe element to the DOM when on-load fires like suggested here: [is there a way to load an iframe asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114239/is-there-a-way-to-load-an-iframe-asynchronously)

**Here's my code:** (pretty much the same as shown in the blog post).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
<body>

  <script>
  (function(d){
    var iframe = d.body.appendChild(d.createElement('iframe')),
    doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;

    iframe.style.cssText = "width:500px;height:500px;"; // simple CSS

    doc.open().write('<body onload="' + 
    'var d = document;d.getElementsByTagName(\'head\')[0].' + 
    'appendChild(d.createElement(\'script\')).src' + 
    '=\'http:\/\/google.com\'">');

    doc.close(); //iframe onload event happens

    })(document);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

There must be something I'm missing, your replies are appreciated.

### The Solution for displaying Dynamic Asynch Iframe, to display pages not scripts:

http://jsfiddle.net/LMB7h/ Hope it helps someone,
Don't forget to swap nytimes.com with your own url.

Comment: `http://google.com` doesn't return a script, what do you expect  when you assign this url as script-src?

Comment: I expect to link it back as an iframe (to see it appear, that's all, I can then do it with my intented page), I put google there as a place holder example, what should I try?

Comment: a script is not an iframe, When you load a script this way it would be evaluated, when the ressource isn't a script all you get is an syntax-error

Comment: regardless, my goal is to link back an iframe and display a page within it, and achieve the loading as explained above, would this not do it?

Comment: I just saw your answer.. well, is there a way to tweak this to display a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you only need to redirect to the desired URL:

```
doc.open().write('<body onload="location.href=\'http:\/\/google.com\'">');
```

This will not work with google, because google's `X-Frame-Options` did not allow the loading in a frame, but for pages which send appropriate headers you should get the desired result.

Comment: Thankyou, apart from the busy indicator working till everything loads,  scripts after the iframe's execute without waiting on it, So it works :)! Could you please tell which part of the script I should edit to make the iframe show in place of an existing div within the Html layout (append it to it somehow). Thankyou so much.

Comment: `var iframe = d.getElementById('someId').appendChild(d.createElement('iframe'))`  , where `someId` is the `id`-attribute of the desired `<div>`