# How to cache iframe in django

Tags: django, django-cache

I am building a django app and one of my templates has a mapstore iframe on it. That iframe is kind of heavy. Is there any way to cahce that iframe, or all the template, i dont have to wait so long every time the page is loaded.
this is the iframe

```
<iframe
    src="http://tedcap.denebinc.com/mapstore/#/viewer/openlayers/1"
    frameborder="0"
    width="100%"
    height="400"
    allowtransparency
></iframe>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114239/is-there-a-way-to-load-an-iframe-asynchronously